# How do I get the file name with it's extension?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried this but this only gets the file name not the extension. How do I get file name with extension?

```
string[] FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);     
string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileList[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Path.GetFileName()

```
string[] FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false); 
string filename =  Path.GetFileName(FileList[0]);
```

Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)